# How do I batch copy/rename/move multiple nested files in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have multiple different files with an identical filename in multiple directories;

```
Folder1/file1.tif
Folder2/file1.tif
Folder3/file1.tif
```

I want all the identical-named files copied/moved into one directory with the directory name prepended to the file name (`Folder1_file1.tif`, `Folder2_file1.tif` ...).

How would I do this copy/rename/move in Command Prompt/Batch?

Answer (score 1):

```
powershell $d='C:\NewFolder\';md $d;ls -r -fo -fi "*.tif"^|%{(cp -Path ($_.FullName) -Dest ($d+$_.Directory.Name+'_'+$_.Name))}
```

- md $d - create directory 'C:\NewFolder\'
- ls -r - get all file in all subdirectory and current directory
- fo = -force - add to list hidden, system and read-only attribyte file
- -fi = -filter "*.tif" - select file tif type
- ^| - `^` - mask transporter/pipe symbol in `cmd`, `|` - pipe `ls` object to `copy` command
- `%` ~ `foreach` ~ `ForEach-Object` - all item cycle
- `cp` = `copy` = `Copy-Item` - copy object at `powershell`
- `$_` - variable for the current object in the pipe line; sample:

  ```
  powershell 'a','B','c','d','F' ^|%{if($_.toLower() -gt 'b'){write $_}}
  ```
- -Path - source in `cp`/`copy`/`Copy-Item` command
- -Dest = -Destination
- `$_.FullName` - a fully path name - source file
- `$_.Directory.Name` - to a parent directory name only
- `$_.Name` - to a file name only
- `($d+$_.Directory.Name+'_'+$_.Name)` - destination path and file name

[image]

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little to explain what this does?  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 Update ver 0.01)